# Override Dictionary<Datetime,int> 's ContainsKey

Tags: c#, containskey

I have a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>` defined like this:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, int> Days;
```

Each `DateTime` is associated to an `int`. I'd like to have a function which indicates if there is already a `DateTime` with the same day in my dictionary:

```
public int GetIntFromDate(DateTime date)
{
    int i = -1;
    if (Days.ContainsKey(date))
    {
        i= CorrespondanceJoursMatchs[date];
    }

    return i;
}
```

This is perfect but I'd like that the `ContainsKey` returns `true` if there is already a `DateTime` with the same Day+Month+Year (without looking at hours/minutes/seconds).

In fact my dictionary shouldn't allow 2 `DateTime` index with the same Day/Month/Year.

A solution could be to create a class with only a `DateTime` attribute and override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, but maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 15):

It's simple: just implement `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>` in a way which just uses `DateTime.Date`, and pass an instance of that implementation to the `Dictionary<,>` constructor. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class DateEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
{
    public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
    {
        return x.Date == y.Date;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
    {
        return obj.Date.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var key1 = new DateTime(2013, 2, 19, 5, 13, 10);
        var key2 = new DateTime(2013, 2, 19, 21, 23, 30);

        var comparer = new DateEqualityComparer();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>(comparer);
        dictionary[key1] = "Foo";
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary[key2]); // Prints Foo
    }

}
```